# Error con SQL server Llaves compuestas

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Este es el modelo con el cual estoy trabajando]

este es el script de la primera tabla

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eva_cat_metodologias] (
    [IdMetodologia]  SMALLINT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DesMetodologia] VARCHAR (200)  NULL,
    [Clave]          VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Explicacion]    VARCHAR (3000) NULL
);
```

y este de la segunda

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eva_plantilla_metodologia] (
    [IdMetodologia]      SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    [IdPlantillaMetodo]  SMALLINT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DesPlantillaMetodo] VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    [FechaReg]           DATETIME      NULL,
    [VersionActual]      CHAR (1)      NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([IdMetodologia]) REFERENCES [dbo].[eva_cat_metodologias] ([IdMetodologia]),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (IdMetodologia,IdPlantillaMetodo)

);
```

Cuando quiero crear la tercera tabla con las llaves foraneas y la llave compuesta no me deja y me coloca el siguiente error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'dbo.eva_plantilla_metodologia' that
>   match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK__eva_plantilla_mo__5441852A'. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

este es el script que estoy tratando de insertar

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eva_plantilla_momentos_metodologia] (
    [IdMomento]         SMALLINT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IdMetodologia]     SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [IdPlantillaMetodo] SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [DesMomento]        VARCHAR (500)  NULL,
    [Objetivo]          VARCHAR (3000) NULL,
    [Secuencia]         SMALLINT       NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (IdMetodologia,IdPlantillaMetodo,IdMomento),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdPlantillaMetodo) REFERENCES [dbo].[eva_plantilla_metodologia] (IdPlantillaMetodo),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdMetodologia) REFERENCES [dbo].[eva_plantilla_metodologia] (IdMetodologia),

 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave de `eva_plantilla_metodologia` es:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (IdMetodologia,IdPlantillaMetodo)
```

Así que una foreign key que apunte a esa clave deberá tener dos campos para almacenar los dos valores de la clave referenciada

```
FOREIGN KEY (IdMetodologia, IdPlantillaMetodo) REFERENCES [dbo]. 
[eva_plantilla_metodologia] (IdMetodologia, IdPlantillaMetodo)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano!! problema resuelto

Comment: @Ricardokr0 te recomiendo si la respuesta te sirvió la marques como aceptada dando click en la flecha a lado de la numeración